# ¿Cómo puedo exportar resultados de un análisis a un data Frame o excel?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, rstudio, tidyverse

quiero pedir ayuda con el siguiente tema.
Tengo el siguiente código en R:

```
for (i in 1:500) print(
gasto_promedio_2020 %>% 
  filter(DEPEN == "CORP", MATRICULA > i) %>% 
  group_by(DEPEN) %>% 
  summarise(mean(GASTO_PROMEDIO)))
```

y lo que necesito es que los resultados sean guardados en un data Frame o exportados excel.

gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siempre cuando necesito sacar comentarios desde un bucle acudo a una lista. Cada casillero de la lista guardará una pequeña data frame con el resultado de la iteración `i`. Después de la ejecución del bucle, puedes juntar todos los pequeños data frame creados con `do.call()`

```
resultados <- list()

for (i in 1:500){
  gasto_promedio_2020 %>% 
    filter(DEPEN == "CORP", MATRICULA > i) %>% 
    group_by(DEPEN) %>% 
    summarise(mean(GASTO_PROMEDIO))) -> resultados[[i]]
} 
  
resultados_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,resultados)
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfecto.